# How to customize date-fns's formatRelative?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

In moment, with [calendar](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/), I can customize how to show the time like below

```
moment(dateTime).calendar(null, {
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

In date-fns, based on the [formatRelative](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.7/docs/formatRelative), I can provide `options`.

```
formatRelative(dateTime, Date.now(), options);
```

However, after reading `options` document, I still cannot figure out how to customize it.

Any guide will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An update on the accepted answer: it looks like in the latest version of `date-fns`, the format strings look slightly different (single quotes instead of braces):

```js
import { formatRelative } from 'date-fns';
import { de } from 'date-fns/esm/locale';

const formatRelativeLocale = {
  lastWeek: "'letzten' dddd 'um' LT",
  yesterday: "'gestern um' LT",
  today: "'heute um' LT",
  tomorrow: "'morgen um' LT",
  nextWeek: "dddd 'um' LT",
  other: 'L LT', // Difference: Add time to the date
};

const locale = {
  ...de,
  formatRelative: token => formatRelativeLocale[token],
};

const text = formatRelative(date, new Date(), { locale });
```

Also see [this example of the format string specified in the `date-fns` source](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/e4ffe1537a0dfddddfd24697b976915cd366b10b/src/locale/en-US/_lib/formatRelative/index.js).

Answer (score 15):

Although date-fns does not support a native method to do partial overwrites (yet), you can do the following, to do some manual tweaking (shown here by the german locale):

```
import { formatRelative } from 'date-fns';
import { de } from 'date-fns/esm/locale';

const formatRelativeLocale = {
  lastWeek: '[letzten] dddd [um] LT',
  yesterday: '[gestern um] LT',
  today: '[heute um] LT',
  tomorrow: '[morgen um] LT',
  nextWeek: 'dddd [um] LT',
  other: 'L LT', // Difference: Add time to the date
};

const locale = {
  ...de,
  formatRelative: token => formatRelativeLocale[token],
};

const text = formatRelative(date, new Date(), { locale });
```